# Prove $h(n)\leq h (\lfloor n/2 \rfloor) +1$ where $h(k)$ denotes the $k$th harmonic number

Tags: harmonic-numbers

Can someone tell me how to prove that the harmonic numbers

$$h(n) = \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{k}$$

satisfy the inequality

$$h(n) \leq h(\lfloor n/2\rfloor) + 1\,?$$

Comment: Yes, use induction. Think about the inductive step..., what is it?

Comment: Is it solved as a floor function??

Answer (score 5):

$\begin{array}\\
H(2n)
&=\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac1{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac1{k}+\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac1{k}\\
&=H(n)+\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac1{k}\\
&<H(n)+\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac1{n}
\qquad \text{ since }\frac1{n} > \frac1{k} \text{ for } k > n \\
&=H(n)+n \frac1{n}\\
&=H(n)+1\\
\end{array}
$

Also note that

$\begin{array}\\
H(2n)
&=H(n)+\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac1{k}\\
&>H(n)+\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac1{2n}
\qquad \text{ since }\frac1{2n} \le \frac1{k} \text{ for } k \le 2n \\
&=H(n)+n \frac1{2n}\\
&=H(n)+\frac12\\
\end{array}
$

(added in response to a comment)

$\begin{array}\\
H(2n+1)
&=\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} \frac1{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac1{k}+\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n+1} \frac1{k}\\
&=H(n)+\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n+1} \frac1{k}\\
&<H(n)+\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n+1} \frac1{n+1}
\qquad \text{ since }\frac1{n+1} > \frac1{k} \text{ for } k > n+1 \\
&=H(n)+(n+1) \frac1{n+1}\\
&=H(n)+1\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: what about the floor function?? we have to show it as a floor function ??

Comment: That's why I did 2n instead of n.

Comment: so is it like for 2n we dnt need floor function?

Comment: Exactly. I view this as going from $n$ to $2n$ to ... $2^kn$, not the other way (i.e., successive divisions by 2).

Comment: This is only half of the solution (the easiest one). One also needs to prove that h(2n+1)⩽h(n)+1 for every nonnegative integer n.

Comment: I just added that. Turned out to be relatively easy.